# Android xml selector for layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I was wanting to know if there is a selector for layouts like there is for drawables.

Example of selector with drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_library_clicked"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_library_not_clicked" />
```

But is it possible to have something like this (This code below didn't work for me but it should give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected -->
<item android:layout="@layout/tab_library_clicked"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected -->
<item android:layout="@layout/tab_library_not_clicked" />
```

Comment: How exactly are you planning to use such a thing ?

Comment: @Mr.Me I wanted to use this for TabSpec.setIndicator().  I tried the first xml code I linked but the images were not filling up the tab specified to look good.  But when I created a layout with an ImageView and did match_parent for width and height to fill up the tab it looked a lot better so I was wondering if there was a way to do the second xml code I put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't exist.

The most "sophisticated" you'll be able to do with a selector in XML probably is using a [drawable layer list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) to combine several drawables onto one state.

Alternatively you can try using the touch_down and touch_up events to programmatically call `setVisibility()` on the layouts, but I imagine the performance will be very poor.

Comment: drawable list is very helpful in such cases

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you are looking for is a way to propagate parent's state to its child views.
That way whenever the indicator state changes (selected, not) the imageview state changes.

android already have an xml attribute for that.

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

use this with your child views in the layout file and combine it with the selector.
for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f00" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Default Selector mechanism only provides alternatives for properties (such as drawable to use etc), depending on a view's state. It does not replace the Views themselves. The functionality you are asking for is not available.

Selected state for a View is bound to  one of the values of `*_STATE_SET` fields in the `View` class. Combined state of a view is retrieved via [`getDrawableState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawableState%28%29).

You can extend a View class and make use of these states to do something custom. Or,
you can develop a custom layout controller, that watches state changes across the View tree and replaces child views according to an xml resource.

But the effort is not worth it because:

1. The view/layout structure must remain the same during a user's interaction with it. You shouldn't change a button into a check-box when user selects it, replacing views/layouts like that is simply confusing UX-wise.
2. You only need to modify the looks of a view on user interaction, which is already provided by selector based draw-ables and colors.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such attribute `android:layout` for `item` in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). It is supposed to be used with `android:drawable`.

Comment: I know this.  I am asking if there is anything that can select a layout based upon the state_selected like there is for drawables.

Comment: and that's what i actually answered. I could answer **`Sorry, It is not possible!`** too but thought to give you some explanation which i think didn't go well in your case :)

Comment: No you didn't answer my question.  I was not asking if android:layout for <item> exist/works, I know this since it didn't work like I said in the original post.  All I am asking is if there is anything that can simulate the logic the second xml code I posted with all that xml has to offer.  If "it is not possible" then give me the reason such as there is not such attribute at all in xml with android:layout thus you cannot do such a thing, not just for <item> :).

Comment: Item has a limited scope which only works with drawables. Not all attributes are common/available for all different types of tags. You cannot say if an attribute available for one tag must be available in another just because it is available in the framework.