# Highlight a Single Row in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am inflating a layout multiple time as per records.so i want when the user select any particular row.It gets highlighted and after that it comes in normal state as it was before.How can we do this.

**Layout that i am inflating multiple times**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainResultLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/request_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="25 Sep 2013" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trip_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="XXXXXXXXXX" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/approval_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pending"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me how we can do this .Will be thankful to u ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight a Layout use Selector. Selector can be used to layout,widgets like TextView,Button etc.

artists_list_backgroundcolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/grey" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="grey">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="itemselected">#EDEDED</color>
</resources>
```

**Use selector like this.**

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="@drawable/artists_list_backgroundcolor">
```

Answer (score 0):

xml selector for layouts whats you need.

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142923/android-xml-selector-for-layouts) maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [how can i get android list view selector items to remember their state off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728240/how-can-i-get-android-list-view-selector-items-to-remember-their-state-off-scree/18728917#18728917)

It's basically using a `Checkable` `RelativeLayout` but you can do the same for `LinearLayout`.